# Does adding a field re-index all fields for all documents?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I have a large CloudSearch domain (5m documents) with three indexed fields.

I want to set the default search field to a new empty field ([as per](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/9065727977831062#_Ref202334511)). If I add this field do all fields in existing documents get re-indexed?

I want to be careful because I don't want to incur a large fee when re-indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a new field, all documents (and the fields in them) get reindexed. There's no way to avoid this unfortunately.

It's mentioned [here in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/indexing.html) as well as [on the pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/pricing/).

Comment: Thanks. In the end I waited for the next big upload of data to a new domain and set the blank field in there.

Comment: This is no longer true, adding new columns requires manually re-indexing. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/indexing.html